# What is the ASP.NET security client services profile provider data type?

Tags: asp.net, security, profile-provider

This seems to be a simple question, but I cannot find the answer after much searching.

I have an application that uses the ASP.NET security system.  The membership uses a `System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider` type for the provider, and the roles, similarly, uses the `System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider` type.  Obviously, this application does NOT make a direct connection to the ASP.NET security DB, but uses these proxy classes when connecting to the configured serviceUri to get the security data.

What is the data type I should use for the provider of the profile information, using the same client services proxy method?